# Why is my function running without asking for the input first?

Tags: python

So I am trying to work on a project for school and I wanted to create a prompt function that would allow me to enter in the question, type of prompt, the function that it would run if the input was "Y", and the response string it would output if the user replied "N".
This is my code:

```
#Will Steve Become a Millionaire?
#Interactive Fiction
#Zachary Williams

##Type 0 prompt = Y/N, Type 1 prompt = Int input.

def prompt(question, qType, yFunction, nResponse):
    print(question)

    answer=input()

    if qType==0:

        if answer=="Y" or answer=="y":
            yFunction()

        elif answer=="N" or answer=="n":
            print(nResponse)

        if answer=="X":
            print("test")

        else:
            print("\"" + answer + "\" is not one of the options. Please type \"Y\" or \"N\".")

    elif qType==1:
        print("test")

    else:
        print("Error creating prompt.")

##Start the story.
def start_program():
    print("It was 3:45 AM on a Saturday night. The only light in the room shone upon Steve's face, coming from the screen of his laptop, which he had been staring at for almost 12 hours straight. This was nothing new for Steve, but then an email popped up.")

    prompt("\nWould you like to read the email? (Y/N)", 0, open_email(), "Steve closed the notification. It was time to go to bed.")


def opening():
    print("Will Steve Become a Millionaire?")

    prompt("Starting the program.", 0, start_program(), "Okay then.")

def open_email():
    print("\nSteve opened the email.")
    print("\n\"I am Prince Kufour Otumfuo,\" the email read, \"I am transferring $75,000,000 USD to the United States, and need your help to transport it into the country. If you help me do so, I will only have you transfer $65,000,000 to my account, leaving you with $10,000,000 to keep. If you would be so kind, please reply to this email.\"")

opening()
```

Currently, this is what it returns when I run the program:

Will Steve Become a Millionaire?
It was 3:45 AM on a Saturday night. The only light in the room shone upon Steve's face, coming from the screen of his laptop, which he had been staring at for almost 12 hours straight. This was nothing new for Steve, but then an email popped up.

Steve opened the email.

"I am Prince Kufour Otumfuo," the email read, "I am transferring $75,000,000 USD to the United States, and need your help to transport it into the country. If you help me do so, I will only have you transfer $65,000,000 to my account, leaving you with $10,000,000 to keep. If you would be so kind, please reply to this email."

Would you like to read the email? (Y/N)

Where it says "Steve opened the email." it should be asking "Would you like to read the email? (Y/N)", Instead, it's asking that after it prints it out. I'm very confused on why this is. Sorry if I didn't format this properly, I have never posted on here before.

Thanks!

Comment: Thats because you are calling the `start_program()` function while calling `prompt` instead of passing the function object.Try changing to `prompt("Starting the program.", 0, start_program, "Okay then.")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the below line in the `opening()` function from

```
prompt("Starting the program.", 0, start_program(), "Okay then.")
```

To

```
prompt("Starting the program.", 0, start_program, "Okay then.")
```

Note that I have removed the `()`. I think you need to pass the function object instead of calling the function.

Comment: This worked! Thank you for the help. What is the difference between calling and passing a function?

Comment: @ZacharyWilliams :  In Python functions are objects as well and u can pass them as arguments. From ur code what u r trying to do is, u r passing the start_program function object to the prompt function and the calling happens based on the `if` condition inside it, which is basically, `yFunction()`. This is where `start_program` is getting called. Glad to help you :)

Comment: @ZacharyWilliams: calling a function by appending the "()" *executes* it immediately.  Passing the function's name without the "()" allows it to be executed later.  In your original code, the function is EXECUTED as it is being evaluated as an argument, long before "prompt()" is being called.

Comment: I appreciate the the explanations. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask input there something like this:

```
#Will Steve Become a Millionaire?
#Interactive Fiction
#Zachary Williams

##Type 0 prompt = Y/N, Type 1 prompt = Int input.

def prompt(question, qType, yFunction, nResponse):

  print("y",question)

  answer=input()

  if qType==0:

    if answer=="Y" or answer=="y":
      yFunction()

    elif answer=="N" or answer=="n":
      print(nResponse)

    if answer=="X":
      print("test")

    else:
      print("\"" + answer + "\" is not one of the options. Please type \"Y\" or \"N\".")

  elif qType==1:
    print("test")

  else:
    print("Error creating prompt.")

##Start the story.
def start_program():
  print("It was 3:45 AM on a Saturday night. The only light in the room shone upon Steve's face, coming from the screen of his laptop, which he had been staring at for almost 12 hours straight. This was nothing new for Steve, but then an email popped up.")

  input_1=input("\nWould you like to read the email? (Y/N)")

  if input_1 == "Y" or input_1 == "y":
      open_email()

  elif input_1 == "N" or input_1 == "n":
      print('Okay then')

  if input_1 == "X":
      print("test")





def opening():
  print("Will Steve Become a Millionaire?")

  prompt("Starting the program.", 0, start_program(), "Okay then.")


def open_email():
  print("\nSteve opened the email.")
  print("\n\"I am Prince Kufour Otumfuo,\" the email read, \"I am transferring $75,000,000 USD to the United States, and need your help to transport it into the country. If you help me do so, I will only have you transfer $65,000,000 to my account, leaving you with $10,000,000 to keep. If you would be so kind, please reply to this email.\"")

opening()
```

or call a function like `function`  instead of `function()`

```
#Will Steve Become a Millionaire?
#Interactive Fiction
#Zachary Williams

##Type 0 prompt = Y/N, Type 1 prompt = Int input.

def prompt(question, qType, yFunction, nResponse):

  print("y",question)

  answer=input()

  if qType==0:

    if answer=="Y" or answer=="y":
      yFunction()

    elif answer=="N" or answer=="n":
      print(nResponse)

    if answer=="X":
      print("test")

    else:
      print("\"" + answer + "\" is not one of the options. Please type \"Y\" or \"N\".")

  elif qType==1:
    print("test")

  else:
    print("Error creating prompt.")

##Start the story.
def start_program():
  print("It was 3:45 AM on a Saturday night. The only light in the room shone upon Steve's face, coming from the screen of his laptop, which he had been staring at for almost 12 hours straight. This was nothing new for Steve, but then an email popped up.")

  prompt("\nWould you like to read the email? (Y/N)", 0, open_email, "Steve closed the notification. It was time to go to bed.")


def opening():
  print("Will Steve Become a Millionaire?")

  prompt("Starting the program.", 0, start_program(), "Okay then.")

def open_email():
  print("\nSteve opened the email.")
  print("\n\"I am Prince Kufour Otumfuo,\" the email read, \"I am transferring $75,000,000 USD to the United States, and need your help to transport it into the country. If you help me do so, I will only have you transfer $65,000,000 to my account, leaving you with $10,000,000 to keep. If you would be so kind, please reply to this email.\"")

opening()
```